# (iPhone) Reading from a web file - NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, nsmutablearray

Right now I have an NSArray whose items are just written in the implementation file.

I'd like to know how to make it so I can store all the items on a web (text) file. Example:

> http://mysite.com/files/objects.txt

On that document:

```
Object 0 goes here
Object 1 goes here
Object 2 goes here
Object 3 goes here
```

etc. All separated by a line break.

How would I be able to do this? And when I update that text file, I'd like the objects to update as well. I'd do this via an NSMutable array, correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSArray*)getObjectsFromWeb {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/files/objects.txt"];
    NSStringEncoding usedEncoding;
    NSError *error;
    NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                          usedEncoding:&usedEncoding
                                                 error:&error];

    return [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

after `data` is assigned here, `usedEncoding` (and possibly `error`) will have a value that you can inspect and tak action on if you like.